# use R in the background of a website to generate statistics

Tags: r, web, statistics

I would like to use R to calculate on demand some statistics on a website. (eventually plot results)
Is it possible? Using which tools? I need the method to be multithreaded as several users can access the website at the same time. Eventually, a LOT of users may need to access the system at the same time.

Comment: This is incredibly vague.  Could you expand and clarify?

Comment: Seconded. R-on-the-web frameworks have existed for well over a decade.  Even the R FAQ has an entry on this. Also see Rserve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at [RApache](http://rapache.net/) and also maybe [Rook](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rook/index.html).

Comment: ...and [brew](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brew/index.html), and [websockets](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/websockets/index.html), and [webvis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webvis/index.html), and [sinartra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sinartra/index.html), and [googleVis](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/index.html), and [RJSONIO](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJSONIO/index.html), and... this isn't helpful anymore. :)